# jquery setting an inline width property problem

Tags: jquery, width, jcarousel

I am using a jcarousel, and I need to explicitly specify the width of each img. The problem is, that it has to actually see the width="" to work. Is there a way to add an inline width to image. I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.tab-item-photo img').each(function () {
        $(this).css("width", "100px");
    });

});
```

It changes the image size but it doesn't add the width to inline style so the functionality of jcarousel doesn't work.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks,
H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's setting the css property, but it sounds like you're talking about the width attribute. Try `$(this).attr('width', '100px');`

EDIT: There's actually an easier way to implement the same thing that would be a bit less verbose.

Your statement above would be the equivalent of

```
$('.tab-item-photo img').css('width', '100px');
```

If changing `css` to `attr` doesn't work, you could also try adding it to the style attribute. If you know the style attribute is already empty, you could do

```
$('.tab-item-photo img').attr('style', 'width:100px');
```

Otherwise, you would have to parse width out of the existing style attribute and add it back in. Ideally, you would just do this with `.css()` but that apparently doesn't play well with your jcarousel code.

Comment: I haven't used jcarousel, but that sounds odd. You just replaced `css` with `attr` in your code?